# IoC StructureMap resolve named instance

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

For the following code how would I resolve based on the name?

```
public interface IService
{}

public class ServiceA : IService
{}

public class ServiceB : IService
{}

public class ClassA
{
    public IService service { get; set; }

    public ClassA(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public IService service { get; set; }

    public ClassB(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Registry:

```
public class MyRegistry : Registry
{
    public MyRegistry()
    {
        For<IService>().Add<ServiceA>().Ctor<IService>().Is(i => i.GetInstance<IService>("ServiceA")); // error
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
container = new Container(new MyRegistry());
var test = container.GetInstance<ClassA>();
```

**Problem:**

- For **ClassA** IService => should yield ServiceA
- For **ClassB** IService => should yield ServiceB
- Also, Is there a way to use attributes in the constructor to specify concrete implementation for specific type? (so it doesn't have to be specified in the configuration?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working like this> @ozczcho's answer helped. thanks

```
    For<ClassA>().Use<ClassA>().Ctor<IService>("service").Is<ServiceA>();
    For<ClassB>().Use<ClassB>().Ctor<IService>("service").Is<ServiceB>();
```

Answer (score 0):

We have created our own RegistrationConvention (note this implementation registers each plugin family as Singleton):

```
    public class SingletonConvention<TPluginFamily> : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (!type.IsConcrete() || !type.CanBeCreated() || !type.AllInterfaces().Contains(typeof(TPluginFamily)))
            return;

        registry.For(typeof(TPluginFamily)).Singleton().Use(type).Named(type.Name);
    }
}
```

And then in our Registry (untested below):

```
        Scan(y =>
        {
            y.With(new SingletonConvention<IService>());
            y.Assembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
        });

        For<ClassA>()
            .Use<ClassA>()
            .Ctor<IService >("service").Is("service",x =>
            {
                var service = x.GetInstance<IService>().Named("ServiceA");

                return service;
            })
```